# For loop not looping

Tags: javascript, json

Having some minor problems with a loop I'm doing. It doesn't seem to be running, even though all the conditions should be met...

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i > obj.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);

    if (obj[i]["val3"] === true) {
         objReturned = obj[i]["val2"];
    }
}

console.log(objReturned);
```

Simple enough right? Here's how the object roughly looks, I've tried debugging by logging contents of the JSON obj, and I am successfully in retrieving any value using the object notation (eg. `obj[0].Active`).

It's just NOT working in my loop? Am I forgetting something here?

```
[
    {
        "val1": "organisationname1",
        "val2": 1,
        "val3": true
    },
    {
        "val1": "organisationname2",
        "val2": 2,
        "val3": false
    },
    {
        "val1": "organisationname3",
        "val2": 3,
        "val3": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typo:

```
for (var i = 0; i > obj.length; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
              //  ^ There.
```

Comment: Well, you're just magnificent. I'm an idiot, thank you so much :D

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen: No problem ;-) Typo's happen. If a loop's not looping, the loop condition should always be the first thing you check. Then again, I've overlooked stuff like this way too often :P Any way, please consider marking this as the answer, when the cooldown expires.

Comment: I have clicked it frantically for the last 15 minutes. I kinda know, I guess I've been sitting still for too long, usually syntax isn't a problem...

Comment: Sorry, fixed! Can't always be available everywhere.